# How to make Ruby ignore backslash in strings?

Tags: ruby, path

Is there some way in Ruby that I can avoid having to put double-backslash in Ruby strings (like what can be done in C#):

For example, in C# was can prefix a string with `@` and then the backslash in the string does not need to be escaped:

```
@"C:\Windows, C:\ABC"
```

Without `@` we would need to escape the backslash:

```
"C:\\Windows, C:\\ABC"
```

Is there something similar in Ruby?

Comment: Either slash will work to open files on Ruby Windows. Consider just using `/` internally to maintain cross platform compatibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes

```
my_string = 'C:\Windows'
```

See more in the Strings section [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use %q and backslashes will be automatically escaped for you:

```
%q{C:\Windows} => "C:\\Windows"
```